# Using v-for inside component that uses <slot/>

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

So I'm trying to create a dynamic tab component with Vue 3 and slots. I got the tabs working, I have Nav and NavWrapper components. I need to be able to v-for with Nav component inside of a NavWrapper Component. Example:

```html
<NavWrapper ref="selector">
   <Nav v-for="test in testFor" :key="test.name" :title="test.name" icon="bx-user">
       <Profile ref="profile" />
   </Nav>
</NavWrapper>
```

The profile is just another component just for testing.

Inside of NavWrapper template.
Important parts:

```html
<div class="bottom max-h-full">
   <slot />
</div>
```

Script:

```js
setup(props, { slots }) {
    const tabTitles = ref(slots.default().map((tab) => tab.props));
    const selectedTitle = ref(tabTitles.value[0].title);

    provide("selectedTitle", selectedTitle);
    provide("tabTitles", tabTitles);
    return {
      selectedTitle,
      tabTitles,
    };
  },
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'title')
```

I guess I can't get the title of v-for items I tried to put normal ones manually and v-for ones and normal ones work normally but v-for just gives that error.

I console logged tabTitles and that confirms my theory.

```js
0: {title: 'Profile', icon: 'bx-user'}
1: null
```

I tried to put Nav in template tag but same error.

I guess I need to wait for v-for to finish or something, I tried searching on StackOverflow but didn't find anything related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that when rendering `v-for`, Vue 3 template compiler implicitly wraps all generated elements into a Fragment element.

You can check [this example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) - especially the JS tab (generated render function) of `App.vue` and also console (where I'm logging the content of `default()` slot)

So your tabs are not at the root of `slots.default()` but at `slots.default()[0].children`

Comment: Thanks, ```slots.default()[0].children``` Did the trick for me.